# Questions about differences

Tags: discussion, faq

How do we want to handle questions about differences between remakes, adaptations, etc?

I believe questions asking for just general differences between two forms of media (one obviously being a movie version) or between an original vs a remake are **off topic**

Examples:

- [**The Producers**](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/314/what-are-the-main-differences-between-the-new-producers-and-the-original)
- [**Harry Potter**](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/65/i-have-seen-all-harry-potter-movies-i-have-not-read-single-harry-potter-book-d)

However, asking about a specific difference and the reason the movie version had this difference should be **on-topic**

- [**Hannibal**](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/26/why-is-the-ending-to-the-film-adaptation-of-hannibal-completely-different-from)
- [**Different Harry Potter Question**](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/90/why-wasnt-the-poltergeist-peeves-in-the-harry-potter-movies)
- [**Jurassic Park**](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/286/why-are-lexs-and-tims-ages-switched-in-the-film-adaptation-of-jurassic-park)

Opinions gladly welcome.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I perfectly agree with you. peroid.

Comment: yup, same here. you can't easily summarize an adaptation from one media to another, but asking about a **specific** difference could be ok as long as it's signifigant

Answer (score 3):

Ok, I agree with questions being just about 'two forms of media' or format as off-topic.  Completely.  Also I agree about 'adaptations'.

However what is wrong with discussing the differences between an original and a remake?  The question about The Producers is not great and would be closed on other grounds anyway - but in principal why not (good) questions about the differences?

From the examples above, they seem to be poor questions on other grounds, not because they are remakes or adaptations.

Comment: Maybe I'm too broad in using 'remake' as I want to allow questions about *specific* differences.  Got a way to word it better?

Comment: Well, it could go into a 'list questions' section of the FAQ - discouraging questions that turn into lists - of which 'what are the differences between movie A and remake B.

Comment: Yeah, questions that are just "What's the diff?" are just bad.